# 403 USER IS NOT LOGGED IN IN Laravel Spatie

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I am new in Laravel Spatie, and when I fixed some of the problems in my code one by one. When I redirect my view to a webpage *(without the middleware route)* I can freely access it, but when I do it with the middleware route **that error shows up**.

So like when I didn't use a route protection to these 2 routes:

```
Route::get('/adminLogin', function () {
return view('adminLogin');
```

});

```
Route::post('/adminLogin', [AccountsController::class, 'adminLogin'])->name('login.admin');
```

How can I fix it?

> This is my route used:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/admindashboard', function () {
        return view('admindashboard');
    });
```

> My kernel:

```
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'precognitive' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
        'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\PermissionMiddleware::class,
        'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

> My auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'accounts',
        'passwords' => 'accounts',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'accounts' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'accounts',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'accounts' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Accounts::class,
            'table' => 'accounts'
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expiry time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    | The throttle setting is the number of seconds a user must wait before
    | generating more password reset tokens. This prevents the user from
    | quickly generating a very large amount of password reset tokens.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

> My adminLogin:

```
    public function adminLogin(Request $request){
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ];

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            return redirect('admindashboard');
        } else {
            dd('Authentication failed');
            return back();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The best way to log in to the user is via `Auth::login($user)`

Answer (score 0):

Your Middlewares order is incorrect, the Spatie middleware should be priorities over Laravel's Authentication middlewares